# центрирование или выравнивание блока в зависмости от размера внешнего блока

Tags: css, html

Добрый день!
Можно ли посредством css добиться следующего:
1. если размеры блока(div) меньше размеров внешнего блока(div), то он располагается в центре внешнего блока
2. если ширина блока больше или равна ширине внешнего блока, то блок выравнивается по правому краю внешнего блока
3. если высота блока больше или равна высоте внешнего блока, то блок выравнивается по нижнему краю внешнего блока
размеры внешнего блока зависят от размеров окна, размеры внутреннего блока постоянны и могут быть заданы.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нам понадобиться еще одни вспомогательный контейнер, в примере я назвал его **container**. Его мы будем позиционировать по центру при помощи flexbox, а вот то что находиться внутри **container**, а именно блок **item**  мы будем позиционировать при помощи flexbox со свойствами *justify-content: flex-end; и align-items: flex-end;* таким образом, пока элемент **item** равен **container** то все наши элементы находятся в центре, а если **item** не помещается, то он смещается согласно заданным правилам

Добавил пример на https://jsfiddle.net/mdvp65a4/ для удобства

```css
.wrp {
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50vh;
  max-height: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item {
    width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      Я буду в центре пока помещаюсь, а потом буду смещаться влево от правого края и вверх от нижнего края, если не влезу по одной из сторон
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```